# ios android ble corebluetooth 双方向通信

Tags: ios, android, bluetooth

iosではcorebluetooth
android ではbleと認識しています。
ios androidをコードからm対n接続もしくは1対m接続をbluetooth/bleで行い双方向で何か文字列等の送受信を行うことは可能ですか？？

可能であれば、キーワードなど教えていただけたら嬉しいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

大体、774RRさんが回答してるので別視点から、回答します。

まず、双方向通信を行うのにBLEを選択する意図が分からないのですが、
そのしたいことって本当にBLEである必要ありますか？

文字列の交換は確かに出来るかもしれません。
BLEはGATTプロファイルに基づいて通信しますが、
GATTの仕様を確認すればサーバとクライアントの関係に近いことが分かるかと思います。

あとGATTで提供されているサービスも確認するといいかもしれません。
このサービス中のどれに自分のやりたいことが当てはまるか考えてみると
BLEである必要性が見えてくるかと思います。
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/

ちなみにAndroid5.0以前ではCentralにしかなれません。
スマホ端末間でBLE通信を行う際には相手側のOSに注意が必要です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。勉強不足ですみません。オフラインであるios,androidを使ってm対nもしくは1対mでの通信を行いたいです。

Comment: できるだけプログラムで自動で通信したく思っています。

Comment: GATTサービス一覧はご覧になりましたか？BLEと言えばiBeaconがパッと思い浮かびますが、他ではヘルス計、歩数計など計測機器と一定間隔で通信しないといけないような場合もBLEの出番です。ドレも情報のフォーマットは決まっているけど何回も通信するため電力消費を抑えなきゃバッテリーがヤバイ！という場合ですね。通信の内容が分からないのですが、それって別にBLEじゃなくて普通のAndroid Bluetooth APIを利用した通信でいいのでは？双方向に通信するような内容が思いつきません。

Comment: はい。さらっとですが確認しました。実装したいのはios androidでのオフラインでの情報の送受信です。wifiなども使わずに出来るだけコードのみでペアリングの操作をユーザー側で最小限に抑えたいと思っています。勉強不足ですが、一応iosでswiftではclassicは自由が聞かないけれど、bleならまだ自由がきくとあったので、androidの方でもbleを使用しようと思っています。通信の内容ですが、大きなファイルを送受信するのではなく、chatでテキストを送り会えれば十分と考えております。

Comment: 加えて返信ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

割とマジで `Bluetooth` 仕様書
仕様書が読めないなら解説書

大前提として `BLE` は `Bluetooth Low Energy` の意味で、通信速度より消費電力削減を優先しています。なのでファイル共有のような大量データのやりとりには全く向きません。

`BLE` は非対称ネットワークであって `Peripheral` と `Central` に役割が分かれます。仕様上 `Peripheral` と `Central` 間にて一定フォーマットの小さなデータを定期的にやりとりするのは得意ですが `Central` 同士 `Peripheral` 同士で通信することはできません。

スマホは通常 `Central` で使います。なのでスマホ同士で通信させることはできません。複数のスマホを `Peripheral` にして `Central` なスマホ１台と接続することはできますが、これは従来通りのサーバークライアントであって p2p ではないです。

---

コメントで質問が追記されたので対応。

`BLE` の通信は周辺装置 (`Peripheral`) とPC本体 (`Central`) の間での通信を最小限の電力で行うことを想定しています。そのため
- 基本は P→C 。だけど、相互に送受信することができます
- 電文内容は固定的なものとなります (GATT Profile で決まる/決める)

例えばキーボードと PC 本体間の通信では HID over GATT Profile を使い
- P→C キー状態一覧を送信 (`Caps` キーが押されている)
- `Central` は自分自身内部の `CapsLock` 状態を更新して
- C→P LED 点灯状況一覧を送信 (`CapsLock` LED 点灯)
別のタイミングでは
- P→C キー状態一覧を送信 (`NumLock` キーが押されている)
- `Central` は自分自身内部の `NumLock` 状態を更新して
- C→P LED 点灯状況一覧を送信 (`NumLock` LED 消灯)
のような通信ができます、というか、そういう通信しかしません。

スマホを `Peripheral` にしても、出来るのはそういう通信のみです。任意の電文を任意のタイミングでやりとりするには `BLE` は向きませんのでご承知おきください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。勉強不足ですみません。オフラインであるios,androidを使ってm対nもしくは1対mでの通信を行いたいです。bleを用いて、1対mは実現可能ということですよね。

Comment: そのcentralとPeripheralはお互いデータを送受信できますか？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。つまり接続のタイミングで、送る電文は固定的になっていると言うことですか？？youtube等で、android ipad iphone のdemo chatを見ました。https://youtu.be/5-QyJEIxO74　ここで使われている技術を試してみたいです。

Comment: ソースコードついてるみたいだしダウンロードして読んでみてはいかが？

Comment: はい！bleのソースコードを片っ端から読んで整形してます！僕が聞きたかったのは、私がやりたいことはbleが最適であるのか？そもそもできるのか？できないもしくは最適ならどういう代替策があるのかです。返信ありがとうございます！

Comment: オイラなら `BLE` でスマホ間通信したいとは微塵も思いませんし、たぶん多くの人が思わないでしょう。それを敢えてやったからネタになっているのであって、オイラを含めて大多数の人は「スゲー（の後に暇人とか＊＊だとかの語が続くでしょう）」という感想になります。向かないの承知でチャレンジするのは止めませんけど、将来の役に立つかどうかはオイラ知らないっす。少なくともオイラの後輩君にはお勧めしないっすね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。iosのandroidはbleでしかオフライン通信できないってことですね。で、代替案も無いと。bleはそこまで万能じゃないと。僕はいろんな技術を勉強したいと思っています。